# How can I scroll a compose Textfield inside a XML NestedScrollView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-nestedscrollview

I've been trying to achieve this behaviour while migrating xml to compose where I have my scrollable NestedScroll and inside I have the reference to the compose element, basically. a Column a few text and a Textfield as TextArea.
So when I write a lot of text in the textfield component this can keep going down but I can't scroll upwards. I set his modifier with a `val scrollState = rememberScrollState(0)` but still doesn't work.
Any ideas how can I solve this situation?

Here's a bit of code

XML:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:overScrollMode="never">

  <androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
      android:id="@+id/compose_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Fragment:

```
 binding.mainComposeLayout.apply {
            setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
     setContent {
         Column(modifier = Modifier.padding()) {
            Text()
            TextArea(modifier = Modifier)
            Button()
       }
    }
}
```

TextArea:

```
@Composable
fun TextArea(){ 
val scrollState = rememberScrollState(0)
    Column(modifier = modifier) {
        TextField( modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(150.dp)
                .verticalScroll(scrollState))
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well... finally I decided to get rid off almost all of my XML and now I don't need to worry about the nestedScrollView anymore.

Comment: That's not much of an answer.